# Variation of parameters for ODES with distributions as coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

In my work, I encounter the following type of equation. Consider a non-homogeneous system
\begin{equation}
X'=A(t)X+f(t),\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)
\end{equation}
where $X$ is a $n$-dimensional vector valued function of the real variable $t$ and $A(t)$ is an $n\times n$ matrix valued integrable (on $\mathbb{R}$) function of $t$. If $f$ is smooth and if a fundamental matrix solution of the homogeneous equation $\Phi$ is known, then variation of parameter gives us the following solution to (1)
$$
X=\Phi(t)\int^t \Phi^{-1}(t') f(t')dt'.
$$
What about if $f$ is a distribution or, less generally, belongs to a Sobolev space $H^\gamma$ with negative $\gamma$? I have fairly certain that the same formula works in the distribution sense but I would like to have a reference with some theorems (perhaps giving some restrictions on $f$) to know for sure it is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is a distribution (1) may not be meaningful pointwise, so presumably what you mean is a weak solution, i.e. $X$ should be a distribution such that
for any test function $\phi$,

$$  \langle \phi, A X + f - X' \rangle = \langle A^T\phi + \phi', X \rangle 
+ \langle \phi, f \rangle  = 0 $$

I think you'll want to assume $A$ is smooth as a function of $t$, so that $A^T \phi$ is a test function.

Write $X(t) = \Phi(t) Y(t)$ where $\Phi(t)$ is a fundamental matrix, so $\Phi' = A \Phi$.  Then this becomes

$$ \langle (\Phi^T \phi)', Y \rangle + \langle \phi, f \rangle = 0 $$
But 
$$ \langle (\Phi^T \phi)', Y \rangle = - \langle \Phi^T \phi, Y' \rangle
= - \langle \phi, \Phi Y' \rangle$$
so we get

$$  Y' = \Phi^{-1} f $$

and thus

$$X(t) = \Phi(t) Y(t) = \Phi(t) \int^t \Phi^{-1}(s) f(s)\; ds $$

Comment: And the "integral"/antiderivative is nonunique.

Comment: Concerning the non-uniqueness (thanks to @mathematician above), is it possible to fix the anti-derivative by having a definite integral from a real value $a$ $\int_a^t \Phi^{-1}(s) f(s)\; ds$, where $a$ is outside the singular support of $f$. But perhaps it does not matter if $a$ is in the singular support? Thank you.

Comment: As usual, the difference between two weak solutions of $X' = AX + f$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation $X' = AX$, which will be $\Phi(t) c$ for some constant vector $c$.  That's where the non-uniqueness of the antiderivative comes in.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. I was just wondering if it made sense for example if we want to choose the solution that is zero at $x=a$, to write $X(t)=\Phi(t)\,\int_a^t \Phi^{-1}(s) f(s)\; ds$, even though $f$ is a distribution.

Comment: This could be problematic if $f$ is singular at $a$.